# Linking html element with array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to web development and working with plain javascript. I have a long table in HTML in which most of the cells are `input`. I want to detect changes in each cell. I'm linking the html inputs with the list of data that I fetched from the database so I can directly modify html with a change in any object, respectively. I want to add an attribute named `element` inside the object, which will contain the html `input` object.

`list of objects from db => want to add "element" attribute to every object`

```
async function refillTable() {

    // Clearing the table
    while (semesterTable.firstChild) {
        semesterTable.removeChild(semesterTable.firstChild);
    }

    // Populating the table
    subjectsList = await data.getSubjectsList(parseInt(currentPaginationItem.innerText));

    let tableHeading = "<tr><th>-</th>";

    const subjectsNameArray = Array.from(subjectsList.reduce((result, subject) => {
        result.add(subject.sid);
        return result;
    }, new Set()));

    subjectsNameArray.forEach((subject) => {
        tableHeading += `<th>${subject}</th>`;
    });


    tableHeading += "</tr>";
    semesterTable.innerHTML += tableHeading;

    let inputIdNumber = 1;

    for (let user of usersList) {

        let tableRow = "<tr>";
        tableRow += `<td>${user.name}</td>`;

        const rowValues = Array.apply(null, Array(subjectsNameArray.length));
        let subjectElementIds = new Map();

        subjectsList.forEach((subject, subjectIndex) => {
            if (subject.uid === user.uid) {
                const index = subjectsNameArray.indexOf(subject.sid);
                subjectElementIds.set(
                    `input_${inputIdNumber}`,
                    subjectIndex
                );
                rowValues[index] = `<td><input id="input_${inputIdNumber}" value="${subject.obtainedMarks}"></td>`;
                inputIdNumber++;
            }
        });

        for (let value of rowValues) {
            if (typeof value === "undefined") {
                tableRow += '<td>Undefined</td>';
            } else {
                tableRow += value;
            }

        }

        tableRow += "</tr>";

        semesterTable.innerHTML += tableRow;
    
        for (let [id, subjectIndex] of subjectElementIds) {
            subjectsList[subjectIndex].element = document.getElementById(id);
        }
    
        subjectElementIds.length = 0;
    }
    subjectsList[4].element.className = "test";
    console.log(subjectsList[4].element);

}
```

DEBUG:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSA3s.png)

This code is not working but when I modify any element inside the outer for loop, it works fine.

Like this:

```
for (let [id, subjectIndex] of subjectElementIds) {
    subjectsList[subjectIndex].element = document.getElementById(id);
}
    
subjectsList[4].element.className = "test"; // moved inside outer loop
console.log(subjectsList[4].element); // moved inside outer loop
```

DEBUG:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAAeC.png)

If I change it anywhere else outside the outer loop, it will not reflect changes to the HTML. Why is this happening?

EDIT:

I've tried changing `subjectElementIds` to an array and using `forEach` to iterate, but still it has not worked.

UPDATE:

Now I found that it is only working for the current iteration of the outer for-loop. If I try to modify it after the iteration in which it was set, it no longer reflect changes to the HTML.

Here is fiddle which I'm trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/Dev_Shao/nfh52dum/19/

Comment: `for (let [id, subjectIndex] of subjectElementIds)` is invalid . check [mdn for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: @Anilkumar Why is this invalid? I've read the documentation and it seems fine.

Comment: @Anilkumar it is perfectly valid as long as each entry in subjectElementIds is deconstructable (i.e not `null` or `undefined`).
In this case, it is a map, and each entry is an array containing 2 elements (key, value), which are assigned to the variables `id` and `subjectIndex` respectively